# mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card in Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-4

guys, I'm having a problem about my raspberry pi 4

[image]

At first, it works without a problem but after 1 day when I run the raspberry pi 4 again it cant boot properly

I have a 5.1v/3A adapter and tried different sd cards like SanDisk Ultra 32GB, SanDisk EDGE 16 GB, and Miro SDHC 16GB but it just the same output

Comment: Is the '5.1v/3A' adapter a phone charger or a power supply?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - *At first it works without a problem* :p

Comment: have you made any changes at all to the boot partition (specifically in config.txt or cmdlin.txt)

Comment: You mention 4 different SD card brands; have you put the same image on each?

Comment: Error -110 is a timeout. The Pi reads bootcode.bin from the SD card and then runs it. Bootcode.bin then loads the GPU firmware blob and the kernel image. This is where the error is happening. It is failing at the second stage of boot. I suspect damage to the SD card socket, bad cards, or bad Pi hardware.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey i used power supply

Comment: @JaromandaX yea i change the config.txt but its really needed to run the 5inch HDMI LCD(B). I put this:                                                                                
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev If "the SD card simply fails to work from the start", where did the kernel message from? (That is a kernel error message, and note the four raspberries...).  The SD card fails to work *for the kernel*, but that is not "the start", and clearly it worked well enough to load a kernel that could be executed.  Ie., **the entirety of MichealHarvey's comment applies.**

Answer (score 0):

Your micro SD card is dead.  It could have been killed by over-writing (ie, swap) or heat, or simply by failure.   The card should not be used again for data.

There is some small chance you can recover data by putting the card into a reader and another device that understands the filesystems, so a linux desktop.

For completeness, here are the kernel messages in `dmesg` when the card is trash.

```
kernel: usb 4-1.6: new high-speed USB device number 37 using ehci-pci    
kernel: usb 4-1.6: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=0226      
kernel: usb 4-1.6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0     
kernel: usb-storage 4-1.6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected       
kernel: scsi host6: usb-storage 4-1.6:1.0          
mtp-probe: bus 4, device 37: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb4/4-1/4-1.6"         
mtp-probe: 4, device: 37 was not an MTP device      
kernel: scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access Generic Mass-Storage 1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2    
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0      
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 30449664 512-byte logical blocks: (15.6 GB/14.5 GiB)    
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00     
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found      
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through      
kernel: sdc: sdc1 sdc2           
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk       
kernel: usb 4-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 37 using ehci-pci    
kernel: usb 4-1.6: reset high-speed USB device number 37 using ehci-pci    
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery    
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK      
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 88 20 08 00 00
kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 8921096       
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 1048577, lost async page write 
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: killing request          
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] killing request         
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_NO_CONNECT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK       
kernel: sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 00 88 20 80 00 00 08
kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 8921216       
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sdc2, logical block 1048592, lost async page write 
kernel: JBD2: recovery failed           
kernel: EXT4-fs (sdc2): error loading journal
```

Comment: No, it does not necessarily mean the SD card is dead. I have seen this with a microSD card in an SD adapter in a laptop, and just using another SD adapter can also help (even if the SD adapter works with other microSD cards).

Comment: @Supernormal you're probably better adding your own answer, rather than disagreeing with what I posted last year.